# Java HttpUrlConnection response code when connection closed by server

Tags: java, file-upload, httprequest, httpurlconnection, http-response-codes

I am uploading file from android to server using **HttpUrlConnection**. In normal case file upload successful and correct **HTTP response code (200) and message** captured. But server also validates the file being uploaded and can close connection anytime while uploading which prohibits client to upload unnecessary data to server.

In brief, Server has following validation:

**1. File MimeType check:**
If file MimeType isn't any image MimeType then close connection immediately throwing **HTTP response code 415 and message "Unsupported Media Type".** This check done immediately after request arrived in server.

**2. File size check:**
While upload is being progressed as stream, if file size more then 5 MB then server close connection by throwing **HTTP response code 413 and message "Request entity too large"**

Current status:

1. If file is image type AND less then 5 MB upload successful.
2. If file is not image type OR more then 5 MB **unable to get HTTP response code (413 or 415) and message from HttpUrlConnection object.** SocketException or IOException occurs and then invoking `connection.getResponseCode()` throws another exception. Why not `connection` object holds response code and message sent from server ?

Code:

```
package com.example.mahbub.fileuploadrnd;

import android.util.Log;

import com.example.mahbub.fileuploadrnd.util.MimeTypesUtil;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;

public class FileUploadRequest {
    private static final String DEBUG_TAG = "FileUploadRequest";

    public static final int ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY = 0x00;
    public static final int ERROR_UNDEFINED = 0x01;
    public static final int ERROR_HTTP_ERROR = 0x02;

    /**
     * The pool of ASCII chars to be used for generating a multipart boundary.
     */
    private final static char[] MULTIPART_CHARS =
        "-_1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".toCharArray();
    private static final String LINE_END = "\r\n";
    private static final String TWO_HYPHENS = "--";

    String url;
    Map<String,String> mStringParts;
    String filePartName;
    String filePath;
    UploadListener mListener;

    public FileUploadRequest(String url, String filePartName, String filePath, UploadListener listener) {
        this.url = url;
        this.mStringParts = new HashMap<>();
        this.filePartName = filePartName;
        this.filePath = filePath;
        this.mListener = listener;
    }

    public void execute() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                executeRequest();
            }
        }).start();
    }

    public void addStringPart(String name, String value) {
        this.mStringParts.put(name, value);
    }

    public void addStringParts(Map<String, String> parts) {
        this.mStringParts.putAll(parts);
    }

    public interface UploadListener {
        void onSuccess(int responseCode, String response);
        void onError(int errorCode);
        void transferred(long transferred, double progress);
    }

    private void executeRequest() {
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        DataOutputStream outputStream = null;

        String boundary = generateBoundary();

        try {
            URL url = new URL(this.url);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            // Allow Inputs & Outputs
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setUseCaches(false);
            connection.setChunkedStreamingMode(4 * 1024);
            // Enable POST method
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

            // Set header field value
            connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);

            outputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            outputStream.writeBytes(TWO_HYPHENS + boundary + LINE_END);

            // At first write all string parts
            if(mStringParts.size() > 0) {
                for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : mStringParts.entrySet()) {
                    //entity.addTextBody(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
                    String partData = String.format("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%s\"", entry.getKey()) + LINE_END + LINE_END;
                    partData += entry.getValue() + LINE_END;
                    partData += (TWO_HYPHENS + boundary + LINE_END);
                    outputStream.writeBytes(partData);
                }
            }

            // Write file data
            File file = new File(filePath);
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);

            String partData = String.format("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%s\"; filename=\"%s\"", filePartName, file.getName()) + LINE_END;
            partData += String.format("Content-Type: %s", getMimeType(file.getName()));
            partData += LINE_END + LINE_END;
            outputStream.writeBytes(partData);

            // Input stream read buffer
            byte[] buffer;
            // Max possible buffer size
            int maxBufferSize = 5 * 1024;   // 5KB

            // Bytes available to write in input stream
            int bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "File size: " + bytesAvailable);
            // Buffer size
            int bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            // Number of bytes read per read operation
            int bytesRead;

            // Allocate buffer
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            boolean errorOccured = false;

            try {
                while(bytesRead > 0) {
                    try {
                        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
                        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "OutOfMemoryError occurred");
                        errorOccured = true;
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        if(null != mListener) mListener.onError(ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY);
                        break;
                    } catch (SocketException e) {
                        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "SocketException occurred");
                        errorOccured = true;
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        if(null != mListener) mListener.onError(ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY);
                        break;
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "IOException occurred");
                        errorOccured = true;
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        if(null != mListener) mListener.onError(ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY);
                        break;
                    }

                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                    double progress = ((double)(file.length()-bytesAvailable) / file.length());
                    Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Progress: " + progress);
                    if(null != mListener) mListener.transferred(file.length()-bytesAvailable, progress);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                if(null != mListener) mListener.onError(ERROR_UNDEFINED);
            }
            if(!errorOccured) {
                outputStream.writeBytes(LINE_END);
                outputStream.writeBytes(TWO_HYPHENS + boundary + TWO_HYPHENS + LINE_END);
            }

            // Responses from the server (code and message)
            int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            String response = connection.getResponseMessage();

            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Server Response Code: "  + responseCode);
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Server Response Message: " + response);

            InputStream inStream = null;
            if(responseCode >= 200 && responseCode < 400) inStream = connection.getInputStream();
            else inStream = connection.getErrorStream();
            String responseString = readStream(inStream);
            Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "responseString: " + responseString);
            if(responseCode >= 200 && responseCode < 400) {
                if(null != mListener) mListener.onSuccess(responseCode, responseString);
            } else {
                if(null != mListener) mListener.onError(ERROR_HTTP_ERROR);
            }

            fileInputStream.close();
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
            outputStream = null;
            inStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            if(null != mListener) mListener.onError(ERROR_UNDEFINED);
        }
    }

    private String readStream(InputStream iStream) throws IOException {
        //build a Stream Reader, it can read char by char
        InputStreamReader iStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(iStream);
        //build a buffered Reader, so that i can read whole line at once
        BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(iStreamReader);
        String line = null;
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        while((line = bReader.readLine()) != null) {  //Read till end
            builder.append(line);
        }
        bReader.close();         //close all opened stuff
        iStreamReader.close();
        //iStream.close(); //EDIT: Let the creator of the stream close it!
        // some readers may auto close the inner stream
        return builder.toString();
    }

    private String generateBoundary() {
        final StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
        final Random rand = new Random();
        final int count = rand.nextInt(11) + 30; // a random size from 30 to 40
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            buffer.append(MULTIPART_CHARS[rand.nextInt(MULTIPART_CHARS.length)]);
        }
        return buffer.toString();
    }


    /**
     * Get mimeType based on file extension
     * @param fileName
     * @return
     */
    private String getMimeType(String fileName) {
        String[] parts = fileName.split("\\.");
        if(parts.length <= 1) return null;

        return MimeTypesUtil.getMimeType(parts[parts.length-1]);
    }
}
```

Comment: The server resets the connection while you're still sending the data, which is before you've read the response code. You can't possibly get the response code from a reset conection. NB 1. HTTP response codes are sent, not thrown. 2. You are misusing `available()`: see the Javadoc.

Comment: How to catch sent response code and message from server?  **available()** method is belongs to file input stream. How it is related to server response ? We don't know when server close connection. Would you please provide some solution ?